# get repeated data from datatable c#

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I have some data like below in DataTable. Now I want to find the repeated version from dataTable, how can I ?

Here is data :

```
Server1, Database, MySQL,  5.5
Server2, Database, MySQL,  5.1
Server3, OS,       Ubuntu, 10.04
Server1, OS,       Ubuntu, 10.04
Server2, OS,       Ubuntu, 12.04
Server3, Language, Python, 2.6.3
```

Comment: By writing some code, I would imagine.

Comment: What do you mean by want to find the repeated version?
Do you mean you want the values where the OS and its version are present for more than one servers. Like Ubuntu 10.04 ?

Comment: I want only version,

Comment: Maybe it would help if you provided an example of the data output you would like to see.

Comment: I want ' 10.04 ' in my output. I am not able to set filter for most repeating version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq GroupBy like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication31
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Server", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Source", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Version", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server1", "Database", "MySQL",  "5.5"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server2", "Database", "MySQL",  "5.1"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server3", "OS",       "Ubuntu", "10.04"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server1", "OS",       "Ubuntu", "10.04"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server2", "OS",       "Ubuntu", "12.04"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server2", "OS",       "Ubuntu", "12.04"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Server3", "Language", "Python", "2.6.3"});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Version")).ToList();

            var results = groups.Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Count() });

            foreach(var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Version : '{0}' Occurances : '{1}'", item.key, item.count);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```